# Razor View HiddenFor() binds incorrectly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm creating a strongly-typed partial view for a form in ASP.NET mvc, in which I want to use a hidden input to convey the `Id` property of the particular view model. The controller that renders the view accepts an `id` parameter, registered as an option url parameter in my RouteConfig.cs, which is meant to be unrelated.

If the controller is passed a username of `"Tim"` as a routing paramter, and the model that is passed to the partial view has an `Id` of `"e1ac2e44-1e09-4bb4-a7f0-85e1eedf3448"` then here is what happens:

`@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Id)` correctly displays `e1ac2e44-1e09-4bb4-a7f0-85e1eedf3448` as I want it to.

`@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)` incorrectly creates a hidden input with a value of `"Tim"`:

```
<input id="Id" name="Id" type="hidden" value="Tim">
```

The same happens for:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Id)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id, new { value = Model.Id })
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id, new { value = "Obvious eye-catching string" })
@Html.Hidden("Id", Model.Id)
@Html.Hidden("Id", "Obvious string")
```

However, `@Html.Hidden("NotId", Model.Id)` creates a hidden input with the correct value, but not with a name matching the intended property in my view model:

```
<input id="NotId" name="NotId" type="hidden" value="e1ac2e44-1e09-4bb4-a7f0-85e1eedf3448">
```

With further toying around , I've found that `TextBoxFor`, `TextAreaFor` and `EditorFor` all bind in the same way as `HiddenFor` and show up displaying `"Tim"`, not the alphanumeric user ID. This leaves me with two basic questions:

- Why does `@Html.DisplayFor` bind differently from other Razor helpers?
- What is the correct way / easiest work-around to use my view model's property `Id` and not the route parameter `id` apart from changing names?

Comment: Are you using this from within a displayfor or partial?

Comment: @AlexKrupka this is inside a strongly-typed partial view, and not a custom html helper if that's what you are asking

Comment: Hidden for is for passing the param back as a route value. DisplayFor is meant to be used for non route values use display for with a attribute of hidden. Also I'd assume that since DisplayFor is exactly that, it displays only it won't need to look at routeValues HiddenFor (and editorFor) are creating values that are used with route values so will check

Comment: @AlexKrupka I've since resorted to changing the property's name, but that sounds almost worthy of an answer I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting comment with elaboration here..

HiddenFor along with EditorFor are (extension) methods that are used to indicate that the value will be needed to be passed back back with the form. Thus it makes sense that they would look for a specific override from the user on that RouteValue (here you over wrote Id). DisplayFor is the method used just to display the value without it being passed back when the form is submitted. Here since you don't wan't to pass back the current value of Model.Id you should use `@Html.DisplayFor(m=> m.Id,new {Hidden})`